# Mocking ASP Net Core GetService<T>

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, moq

Require help in mocking Dependency Injection `GetService` method in ASP NET Core 5, with MOQ - 4.16.1, Nunit 3

Here is my production code:

```
class SomeClass(){  
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
   
    public SomeClass(IServiceProvider serviceProvider){
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider; 
    }

    void MethodHello(UserType type) {
        var service =  serviceProvider.GetService<Func<UserType, UserTypeBase>>();
                
        Console.WriteLine(service(type).GetAge());
    }
}
    
public enum UserType {
    Male,
    Female
}
```

My Unit tests:

```
class SomeClassTest{

    Mock<UserTypeBase> mockMale = new();
    Mock<UserTypeBase> mockFemale = new();
    
    Mock<IServiceProvider> serviceProvider = new Mock<IServiceProvider>(MockBehavior.Loose);

    [SetUp] 
    public SetUp(){
    
        Func<UserType, UserTypeBase> func = (type) => {
            if (type == UserType.Male)
              return mockMale.Object;
            else return mockFemale.Object;
        };
        serviceProvider.Setup(x => x.GetService(typeof(Func<UserType, UserTypeBase>)))
                       .Returns(func);
        mockMale.SetUp(x => x.GetAge()).Returns(20);
        mockFemale .SetUp(x => x.GetAge()).Returns(50);
    }
    
    [Test]
    public void Test_MethodHello(){
       
        new SomeClass(serviceProvider.Object).MethodHello(UserType.Male);
    
    }
}
```

With this, MOQ framework throws exception:
Object of type 'System.RuntimeType' cannot be converted to type UserType.

Things I have tried:

```
serviceProvider.Setup(x => x.GetService<Func<UserType, UserTypeBase>())
    .Returns(func);

serviceProvider.Setup(x => x.GetService(It.IsAny<Func<UserType, UserTypeBase>>))
    .Returns(func);
```

Nothing seem to work.

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to catch with this test?

Comment: The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear. Can you reformat the question so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do? See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Corrected guys. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code smell aside, I would suggest using an actual `IServiceProvider` to avoid having to arrange the behavior

```
class SomeClassTest{

    Mock<UserTypeBase> mockMale = new();
    Mock<UserTypeBase> mockFemale = new();
    
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    [SetUp] 
    public void SetUp(){
    
        mockMale.SetUp(x => x.GetAge()).Returns(20);
        mockFemale .SetUp(x => x.GetAge()).Returns(50);

        Func<UserType, UserTypeBase> func = (type) => {
            if (type == UserType.Male)
              return mockMale.Object;
            else return mockFemale.Object;
        };

        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddSingleton(func);

        serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        
    }
    
    [Test]
    public void Test_MethodHello(){
       
        new SomeClass(serviceProvider).MethodHello(UserType.Male);
    
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought of this, but the product class under Test has alot more dependencies and hence i wanted just to jeep it simple and to context wanted to mock only required ones. 

However thanks for reply

Comment: @Zenwalker you see this answer satisfies the simple example given. If an example that better matched the actual problem was given then a more target answer could have been provided.